# Drawing custom view at runtime

Tags: android, android-view

Hi I'm having trouble understanding how to draw a custom view at runtime. For simplicity sake, say I have a custom view (Box) that extends the View class, and basically all it does is create a square which is configured to do in my onDraw() method. Now I want to be able to draw this custom view in an activity depending on if the user clicks a button on the activity.

So if the user clicks the button once, one box is drawn, clicks again another box is drawn maybe 10 pixels down etc. I searched for a solution but all I can find is people using a pre-made xml with the view and then using an inflator but I dont want to have a pre drawn box if the user hasn't pressed the button.

Also another quick question: When is onDraw() called or do I have to explicitly call

```
Box box = new Box();
box.onDraw(canvas);
```

Eclipse says that's a suspicious call, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

To make a custom View you have to extend `View` class and override onDraw method. Then when you want to draw this view you have to add it to your view hierarchy. This is as simple    `view.add(new Box())`, where `view` is your root view, this way Android system would invoke `onDraw` method by itself on every rendering cycle. For more information refer to [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).